# Mysql count without deleted

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have an sql query that simply adds a row to an existing database table. The first field is `id` and I assume this value has to be specified in the query.

So then id has to be the number of rows existing + 1. I'm determining the id like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM testtable
```

The problem is that this returns the number of rows that have ever been added, including deleted ones. Because I have been adding and removing from this table, this number is greater than the number of EXISTING rows in the table which is what I want.

How can I count the existing rows in the table instead of the existing + deleted rows?

Comment: Don't do this, just use an autoincrement id value

Comment: Although auto-increments aren't necessarily incremented in that way — e.g. transaction rollback.

Comment: This in general would be a bad idea.. insert id 1, insert id 2, delete id 1, next insert will try to insert id 2 again. Is there any valid reason you don't want to use an auto-increment field?

Comment: Unless your deleted records are still in the table, using COUNT(1) should give you the count of rows, irrespective of the ID field.

Answer (score 5):

If possible switch to using an `auto_increment` column for your id and don't be concerned with  gaps in the sequence of ids. Your own implementation of id generation may inflict more harm  especially in a long run.

Now, back to your immediate question. You are probably looking for this

```sql
SELECT MAX(id) + 1 new_id 
  FROM Table1
```

**Note:** This query might fail under heavy load when several concurrent sessions issuing this 
 query might grab the same id and your subsequent `INSERT` will fail. Therefore again consider using an `auto_increment` for your id.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29d30/1)** demo

Comment: +1. The value of the `id` value inserted in an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column can be retrieved with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Using AUTO_INCREMENT avoids the race condition with concurrent processes where two (or more)  processes retrieve the same `MAX(id)` value, and attempt to insert rows with the same `id` value.

Answer (score 2):

That's a bad idea, because you can end up with duplicate IDs, especially if you delete rows in the middle. If you're not going to use an auto-increment field, you can add the ID to the insert. Just use this in place of the value:

```
((SELECT MAX(t.id) + 1 FROM table t)
```

The full query would then be:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id, col1, col2, col3) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(t.id) + 1 FROM table_name t), :col1, :col2, :col3)
```

Comment: This is essentially what an AUTO_INCREMENT does, although that also works with `INSERT ... VALUES` as well as `INSERT ... SELECT` that insert more than one row. The big advantage of an AUTO_INCREMENT is that the first `id` value inserted can be retrieved with a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`. The value returned by `SELECT MAX(id)` is not guaranteed to return the `id` value of the row inserted by the session, it could be a row inserted by another concurrent session.

Comment: There are times when you can't use an AUTO_INCREMENT, but you still need to increment the ID. For instance, I have a table that's partly inserted from another system with its own IDs, and my own data. I had to figure out how to increment my data without clashing with the IDs from the other source.

Comment: What happens when the data from the other system (with its own ID) attempts to insert a row into your table, and the row has an ID value that clashes with one of the ID values you generated?

Comment: They're different ranges, so hopefully there should be no overlap.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from table
```

will return only the number of entries in it, not based on the ID

Comment: Isn't COUNT(1) equivalent to COUNT(*)? stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Answer (score 0):

There is also possibility to find, and fill the gaps, by picking first free id

```
SELECT MIN(t1.id + 1) AS free_id
FROM t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.id FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id + 1)
```